# lodash filter in array

Tags: javascript, lodash

in lodash there is a possibility to filter within an array which is in an object?

I have an object that has an array in it. It looks like this

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Test 1",
  "tag": ["blue","red", "yellow"]
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Test 2",
  "tag": ["red", "yellow"]
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Test 3",
  "tag": ["green"]
}
```

What I want to do now.
If the tag is Red he should output the object with the ids: 1 and 2. Tag = Green only the object with the id: 3. And so on.

I have now tried to solve this with the lodash filter.

```
 const filteredColors = _.filter(colors, function(c) {
  return _.includes(['Test 1', 'Test 2'], c.name);
});
// returns Objects with 2 Entrys = Correct
```

I can filter normal values, but how can I find the value in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it with:

```
 let filter = _.filter(
  colors,
  _.flow(
    _.property('tag'),
    _.partial(_.intersection, ['red', 'green']),
    _.size,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for lodash, just check if the `tag` array `includes` what you're looking for:

```js
const arr = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Test 1",
  "tag": ["blue","red", "yellow"]
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Test 2",
  "tag": ["red", "yellow"]
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Test 3",
  "tag": ["green"]
}];
console.log(
  arr.filter(({ tag }) => tag.includes('red'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const colors = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Test 1",
  "tag": ["blue","red", "yellow"]
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Test 2",
  "tag": ["red", "yellow"]
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Test 3",
  "tag": ["green"]
}]

function filteredColors(colorsArr, c){
  return colorsArr.filter(i => i.tag.includes(c)).map(i => ({id: i.id}));
}
console.log(filteredColors(colors, 'red'));
console.log(filteredColors(colors, 'green'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array to String, and then you can check string is contain your colour or not. Like.

```
 const items =  [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Test 1",
         "tag": ["blue","red", "yellow"]
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "name": "Test 2",
         "tag": ["red", "yellow"]
      },
      {
         "id": "3",
         "name": "Test 3",
         "tag": ["green"]
 }]

 function findColorId(color){
     return items.filter((d)=> {
         if(String(d.tag).includes(color)){
               return d;
         }
     });
 }

 findColorId('red');
```

Answer (score 0):

This in **lodash** is somewhat longer than with **ES6**.

```js
const data = [{ "id": "1", "name": "Test 1", "tag": ["blue","red", "yellow"] }, { "id": "2", "name": "Test 2", "tag": ["red", "yellow"] }, { "id": "3", "name": "Test 3", "tag": ["green"] }]

// lodash
const lodash = c => _.filter(data, x => _.includes(x.tag,c))

// ES6
const es6 = c => data.filter(x => x.tag.includes(c))

console.log(lodash('green'))
console.log(es6('green'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea in both is to simply use `_.filter` / `Array.filter` and then `_.includes` / `Array.includes`